# Thread pool for std::async

Tags: c++, multithreading, stdthread

In the documentation of [std::async](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/async) it's mentioned that (emphasis mine):

> The function template async runs the function f asynchronously (potentially in a separate thread **which might be a part of a thread pool**) and returns a std::future that will eventually hold the result of that function call.

Is it possible to specify a thread pool for calls to `async`? If not can I somehow check whether a thread pool was used or not?

Comment: No, unfortunately it's not possible.

Comment: There might be implementation details that give this info. For example, on MSVC `std::async` is always async, unless `std::launch::deferred` is specified, and when it is async, it is always in a thread pool.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The standard `std::async` lack of this level of control, although implementation may provide such as non-standard guarantees/extensions.

The lack of this level of control is recognized -- there's https://wg21.link/p0443 proposal to address this.

For now the best option is probably to own thread pool using `std::thread` and `std::packaged_task`.